# Authentication & Authorization in AngularJS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I'm an ASP.NET MVC developer and I recently started to learn AngularJS as it seems like a more modern technology.

However, there's a few complications in my mind when it comes to authentication and authorization in AngularJS. In particular, AngularJS with ASP.NET Web API as the backend.

1. After authentication and getting the token from the api, I would imagine using Angularjs to store the token in the cookie. So any further requests will include the token. Say for some reason, the token expires, the next angularjs request to the api will fail with unauthorized. However, on the client side, angular thinks that it's authenticated (cookies) and will keep using that invalid token on all requests. I can think of a solution, which is to check for the "unauthorized" response on every request and redirect to login if that's the case. But I would probably be shot for such a practice.
2. In ASP.NET MVC, protecting a certain page/resource is as simple as adding [Authorize]. But in angular, it seems to be very complicated. How do I many protect many pages againsted the unauthenticated? Do I have to setup and interceptor for every route, etc?
3. Same goes for Authorization, what if the authenticated user attempts to access, say, the admin panel or parts of admin panel. How do I redirect to unauthorized page if they accessed by direct URL.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways of solving your dilemma, but let me give you some tips that I generally use to authenticate and authorize.

Your app has to authenticate with the API (regardless of .NET or otherwise), which may happen by a login request that sets a cookie (during a server redirect), or perhaps a login endpoint the returns a token (like using oAuth). Either way, you have to store the authorization token so Angular can access it. I use cookies or localStorage myself. Then when a user is authenticated, I have a user service store that so I can use it anywhere in the app.

Once this happens, you can use a [request http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) to attach the authorization header to your request. You can also use a response error interceptor to catch when the token no longer is accepted (usually a 401 status code, easy to check for), and force a login again. This should address issue #1 you raise.

Then for issue #2 and #3, if you are using uiRouter, you can listen for [state change events](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#$stateChangeStart) (particularly `$stateChangeStart`). If I have an admin page, I'll name it `admin.whatever` and then have a change event that checks if the state has admin or not, and redirect users who are not admins. Likewise, I can do the same for all states to detect if there is no currently logged in user and force a login redirect.

Hope that gives you some ideas, it sounds like you're on the right track but need to hook into the Angular features.

Comment: If you have or know of any examples with some of this I would love to see how it's implemented.

Comment: http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-areas-and-border-states-to-control-access-in-an-angular-application-with-ui-router/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but I'm in the same boat as you. I've built some basic Angular pages and small SPA app but now I'm trying to tie it all into an MVC app using .Net Identity. Surprisingly there isn't much out there about this topic. I did come across an good example but it was with .Net Core and MVC 6 which I'm not ready to jump into yet. It's worth watching and might give you some ideas.

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/29/asp-net-5-and-angularjs-part-6-security

A couple days ago I came across this video and for the most part it seems to address the issue. It's the only thing that I've found so far with MVC 5, Angular and some .Net Authorization. Take a look and see if it gives you any ideas. I haven't had a chance to implement it yet but I'm hoping to get started doing that in the next couple of days. If you learn or find anything post it here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f67PFtrldGQ&nohtml5=False